# Group list by choice column

Tags: list, grouping

I've got a list grouped by a choice column which offers 3 values (-, yes, no) by dropdown. Also I've activated the expand Option.

When I view the list the groups are collapsed. If I change the option to collapsed the groups are expanded.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you add somescreen shots of what your View settings look like... one thing... could it be?.. if you (un)collapse by hand in the View, your choice is stored in the local storage of your Browser, and overrides the View setting